# How can I extract the parameters from my expression automatically?

Tags: pattern-matching

I have an expression of this form

$\qquad e^{-x^2b_0+xb_1+b_2}(c_0+c_1x+c_2x^3+c_3x^3+c_4x^4)$

However, it has complicated parameters.

```
(1/(6 Sqrt[π] (1 + Cos[θ]^2 + 
   s^2 Sin[θ]^2)^7))E^(-((
  p0^2 + 3 q0^2 s^2 + x^2 + 3 s^2 x^2 - 
   8 q0 s^2 x Cos[θ] - (p0^2 - q0^2 s^2 + x^2 - s^2 x^2) Cos[
     2 θ])/(
  2 (1 + Cos[θ]^2 + s^2 Sin[θ]^2)))) Sqrt[s]
  Conjugate[Sqrt[
  s]] (-I p0 + q0 s^2 - (-1 + s^2) x Cos[θ]) (I p0 + 
   q0 s^2 - (-1 + s^2) x Cos[θ]) (9 - 4 p0^2 - 6 s^2 - 
   8 I p0 q0 s^2 - 3 s^4 + 4 q0^2 s^4 + 2 x^2 - 4 s^2 x^2 + 
   2 s^4 x^2 + 
   8 I (-1 + s^2) (p0 + I q0 s^2) x Cos[θ] + (-1 + s^2)^2 (3 + 
      2 x^2) Cos[2 θ]) (9 - 4 p0^2 - 6 s^2 + 8 I p0 q0 s^2 - 
   3 s^4 + 4 q0^2 s^4 + 2 x^2 - 4 s^2 x^2 + 2 s^4 x^2 - 
   8 (-1 + s^2) (I p0 + q0 s^2) x Cos[θ] + (-1 + s^2)^2 (3 + 
      2 x^2) Cos[2 θ]) Sin[θ]^6
```

What I want to do is just to match the parameters so I can find the values of $c_0,c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4,b_0,b_1,b_2$.

How can I do that automatically?

Comment: The expression has the form $de^{ax^2+bx+c}$.Where is the second polynomial?

Comment: I think it is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```
type = Boole[FreeQ[#, Power[E, _]]] &;
alltypes = {0, 1};
{bb, cc} = Times @@@ Reap[
  Sow[#, type@#] & /@ List @@ Factor[expr],  (* expr = OP's expression *)
  alltypes][[2, All, 1]] /. 
    {Power[E, p_] :> CoefficientList[p, x], 
     p_ /; ! FreeQ[p, x] && PolynomialQ[p, x] :> CoefficientList[p, x]} // Simplify
```

Comment: Seems like working.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is of the form `a E^b c` where `a` depends only on theta and both `b` and `c` are polynomials in `x`. You can find the list of coefficients by using `CoefficientList[b, x]` and `CoefficientList[c, x]`. You can combine `a` with `c`  and use `CoefficientList[a c, x]` in that case if you want to.

This is assuming, as you wrote your expression, that you know the different parts, `a`, `b`, and `c`. If you were given the entire expression and had to extract the parts from the combined expression it would be much more complicated, but doable with some fancy Mathematica coding.